# turn on show-trailing-whitespace in markdown-mode

Tags: emacs, markdown

I would like to know how to turn `show-ws-toggle-show-trailing-whitespace` on when in `markdown-mode` using the `.emacs` file or the markdown file head like: `<!-- -*- mode: Markdown; [FooBar...] -*- -->`

**Solution:**

```
; open all Markdown files with markdown-mode                                                        
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md$" . markdown-mode))

; set show-trailing-whitspaces in markdown-mode                                                     
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'show-ws-toggle-show-trailing-whitespace)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting this in you init file, will turn on trailing whitespace highlighting for all `markdown-mode` buffers:

```lisp
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'show-ws-highlight-trailing-whitespace)
```

Alternatively, using the `eval` pseudo local variable allows you to turn it on for a specific file:

```
<!-- -*- eval: (show-ws-highlight-trailing-whitespace) -*- -->
```

---

In any case, you have to put this in your init file, to ensure that `show-ws-highlight-trailing-whitespace` is correctly loaded:

```lisp
(require 'show-wspace)
```

Comment: I use emacs 23.3.1 and set markdown-mode in the file head like described in the question. `<!-- -*- mode: Markdown; eval: (show-ws-highlight-trailing-whitespace) -*- -->` -> is not working for me. I tried the `.emacs` addition without success too.

Comment: It seems that I have to activate `markdown-mode` in the init file first to be able to activate 'show-ws-toggle-show-trailing-whitespace'.

Comment: Using `show-ws-toggle-show-trailing-whitespace` instead of `show-ws-highlight-trailing-whitespace` is not a very good idea since it toggles the mode instead of always turning it on. THis could lead to problems if you revert the buffer (try running `M-x revert-buffer` in a markdown buffer and you should see the trailing whitespace highlighted only half of the time.

Comment: On the other hand, `show-ws-highlight-trailing-whitespace` is not an interactive function and is not autoloaded. This means that you have to explicitly load the `show-wspace` package before you can use it (see my edit)